# Is stackoverflow a replacement for a google search?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

In a review I came across, [How to set http_proxy for Chromium in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501894/how-to-set-http-proxy-for-chromium-in-shell).

The question is extremely basic

First result in a Google search for:

```
chrome proxy command line
```

Is this a question worth flagging as low quality?

EDIT:
I have made a overhaul for this post. The original question considered this too basic and begging for votes

Comment: hmm are you sure you're not just reading something into it? After all first questions are from people that are generally looking for help not votes.

Comment: Ironically, I've just been looking at how to do this. I think this question has some value, but perhaps moreso on Super User than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Erm, why do you think that question is begging for upvotes? It doesn't read that way to me at all.

Something may be obvious or easy to you, but that won't necessarily be the case to everyone else.

As the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) says (emphasis mine):

> Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you. We’re all here to learn together. **Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know.** Bring your sense of humor.

Your voting choices are between you and your $deity, but if I were you in this situation, I'd just put up an answer.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see anything about the question that's begging for votes...but I do see a confusing question that could use some steering in the right direction.  Setting up proxies is something that could be done, but could it be done on the command line?  That's a reasonable question to ask, in my opinion.  The way it's *phrased* makes it seem a bit...odd.

I'd ask for clarification from the OP first, and see if they want guidance on setting proxies.  From there, one would either begin looking at how that relates to SO, or provide useful tips on how to do so.

At least, that'd be my approach.